# Visual Studio 2015 community - Regex Find and Replace

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2015, replace, find

I'm trying to write a regex expression to find and replace code within visual studio.

Here are samples of existing code:

```
GameObject go = Instantiate(...);
GameObject go2 = (GameObject)Instantiate(...);
GameObject go3 = ReplaceThis.Instantiate(...);
GameObject go4 = DontReplaceThis.Instantiate(...);
```

I basically need a regex expression to change the snippet to the following:

```
GameObject go = ReplacedClass.Instantiate(...);
GameObject go2 = (GameObject)ReplacedClass.Instantiate(...);
GameObject go3 = ReplacedClass.Instantiate(...);
GameObject go4 = DontReplaceThis.Instantiate(...);
```

As you can see the `DontReplaceThis.Instantiate(...);` is the only one that wasnt replaced.

So far what I have:

```
Find: (?=.*Instantiate)(?=?!DontReplaceThis.)
```

This worked up until the point I added the `?=` logical and for the regex expression.

Edit:

In essence I wish to have a regex expression Find and Replace anything that matches `(.*Instantiate)` but does not contain `DontReplace` before the Member Of Operator for the class scope. It should also append the replacement string to all instances of `.Instantiate` such that they become `ReplacedClass.Instantiate`

Comment: This is hard to understand, can you also put an example of some input text in quotes and your desired output

Comment: @MichaelRandall I added an explanation for the matching conditions to my question. As for the input you can use the first code snippet and its output will be the second code snippet. I'm not sure how else to simplify the example input and output.

Comment: Ahh i get it, you running this on a source file of some sort

Comment: Yes! Its actually **all** the source files in a fairly large project. I need to change the scope of all calls to any variant of a function to a different scope.

Comment: Try [`(?:\w+\.)?(?<!\bDontReplaceThis\.[\w.]*)(\bInstantiate)(?=\()`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cw%2b%5c.%29%3f%28%3f%3c!%5cbDontReplaceThis%5c.%5b%5cw.%5d*%29%28%5cbInstantiate%29%28%3f%3d%5c%28%29&i=GameObject+go+%3d+Instantiate%28...%29%3b%0d%0aGameObject+go2+%3d+%28GameObject%29Instantiate%28...%29%3b%0d%0aGameObject+go3+%3d+ReplaceThis.Instantiate%28...%29%3b%0d%0aGameObject+go4+%3d+DontReplaceThis.Instantiate%28...%29%3b&r=ReplacedClass.%241)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works! Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherLeong Please consider [accepting/upvoting the answer then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658499/3832970).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\w+\.)?(?<!\bDontReplaceThis\.[\w.]*)(\bInstantiate)(?=\()
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5Cw%2B%5C.%29%3F%28%3F%3C!%5CbDontReplaceThis%5C.%5B%5Cw.%5D*%29%28%5CbInstantiate%29%28%3F%3D%5C%28%29&i=GameObject%20go%20%3D%20Instantiate%28...%29%3B%0D%0AGameObject%20go2%20%3D%20%28GameObject%29Instantiate%28...%29%3B%0D%0AGameObject%20go3%20%3D%20ReplaceThis.Instantiate%28...%29%3B%0D%0AGameObject%20go4%20%3D%20DontReplaceThis.Instantiate%28...%29%3B&r=ReplacedClass.%241)

**Details**

- `(?:\w+\.)?` - an optional (as `(...)`, e.g., should not be matched) sequence of

  - `\w+` - 1 or more word chars
  - `\.` - a `.` char
- `(?<!\bDontReplaceThis\.[\w.]*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is `DontReplaceThis.` as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary) followed with 0+ word or `.` chars immediately to the left of the current location (effectively, it fails matches like `var x = DontReplaceThis.Some.Class.Instantiate(...)`, if you need to match it, you will need to remove `[\w.]*`)
- `(\bInstantiate)` - Group 1 (`$1`) that matches `Instantiate`
- `(?=\()` - followed with a `(` char (not added to the match since it is a positive lookahead).

Results:

[image]

Comment: is this: `[\w.]*` meant to match possible nested objects before the call like `DontReplaceThis.SubProperty.SubSubProperty.Instantiate` ?

Comment: @MongZhu Yes, I explained it in the answer. Just paste `var x = DontReplaceThis.Some.Class.Instantiate(...)` in the demo fiddle at regexstorm.net andf you will see it is not matched. Removing `[\w.]*` will match it.

Comment: Perfect, this is best answer <3

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looking for `Instantiate` as a method call and only want to replace it if it is **not** preceded by `DontReplaceThis.` You can use negative lookbehind:

Searchpattern:

```
((\w+\.)|\s)?(?<!DontReplaceThis\.)(Instantiate\()
```

Replacement pattern:

```
ReplacedClass.$3
```

Explanation:

`?<!` match only if not preceded by the following string. (in this case: `DontReplaceThis`)

`((\w+\.)|\s)?` matches optionaly if preceded by either

`\w+\.` any word character occuring 1 or more times followed by a dot

`|` OR

`\s` any white space character

`\(` match opening parentheses. Indication of a method call

`(Instantiate\()` the parentheses defince a group which can be accessed in the replacement pattern by `$3` (inserts the third matched group)

For more information have a look on [regex look-arounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)